# Альтернатива GDI+

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, gdi, gdi+

К сожалению, GDI+ не способна на быструю прорисовку множества объектов в динамике, да я знаю, что она и не создана для этого, но тем не менее. Даже двойная буферизация, многопоточность, перерисовка не всей сцены, а лишь фрагментов и т.д. не дают хорошего результата. Как-то я читал, что GDI+ банально не ускоряется видеокартой, из-за чего даже старенький GDI может обеспечить большее быстродействие. Лично я вижу 4 варианта:

1) GDI

2) Работа с Bitmap побайтово, через LockBits и т.д.

3) DirectX (включая XNA), что для меня сложновато

4) OpenGL (включая MonoGame), аналогично с прошлым пунктом

Вот и хотелось бы уточнить у более знающих, какие варианты могут быть еще. Unity для моих целей - перебор, с нуля осваивать WPF ради этого тоже сомнительно, наверняка должны быть и другие пути.

Comment: WPF не так сложен, как кажется с первого взгляда

Comment: Посмотрите SkiaSharp

Comment: Bitmap хорош, пока сцена не больше одного экрана.  Если у вас сцена в 2-4 раза и больше чем экран... то я через OpenGL переписал програму на с++. OpenGL легче DirectX намного. Для с#... незнаю...

Comment: Проблема XY? Вы сперва опишите, что именно хотите сделать, а потом вам, возможно, посоветуют лучшее решение.

Comment: Хочу написать что-то вроде танчиков (Battle City). Справляюсь с самой механикой, но некоторые графические моменты оставляют желать лучшего: нет плавности картинки  и т.д. Unity, как я уже сказал, излишество. Да, я хочу велосипед, но тем не менее.

Comment: Не нужно никаких альтернатив. GDI+ в WinForms [способна](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotomsg&tid=880616&msg=11576426) обеспечить сотни и тысячи прорисовок объектов в секунду.

Comment: Чуть не забыл: двойная буферизация - DoubleBuffered - наше всё! Устанавливаем в true, наслаждаемся.

Comment: Забавно, конечно.